Showing that the set of theorems deducible from $\Sigma$ is the smallest set with the following conditions
I was reading A Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic, by Christopher Leary and Lars Kristiansen. The section on deductions contains the following proposition:
Proposition 2.2.4: Fix sets of $\mathcal{L}$-formulas $\Sigma$ and $\Lambda$ and a collection of rules of inference. The set $Thm_\Sigma = \{\phi :\Sigma \vdash \phi \}$ is the smallest set $C$, such that:

$\Sigma \subseteq C$
$\Lambda \subseteq C$
If $(\Gamma, \theta)$ is a rule of inference and $\Gamma \subseteq C$, then $\theta \in C$.

Showing that $Thm_\Sigma$ satisfies the three conditions wasn't very hard, but showing that it's the smallest such set has me stuck. The authors provide a partial solution to this second part.
They let $\phi \in Thm_\Sigma$, so that there exists a deduction-from-$\Sigma$ with $\phi$ as its last line. If $\phi$ is a logical axiom $(\phi \in \Sigma)$ or a nonlogical axiom $(\phi \in \Lambda)$, then  $\phi \in C$ by (1) or (2), respectively. Otherwise, $\phi$ must be justified by virtue of a rule of inference $(\Gamma, \phi)$. The next part is what's confusing me: they say that therefore, each $\gamma \in \Gamma$ is an element of $C$, and that this is really a proof by induction on the shortest deduction of $\phi$, and this part (the part about each $\gamma \in \Gamma$ being in $C$) is where we use the inductive hypothesis. The details are left as an exercise. The following is my attempt:
Proof:
Let $C$ be a set satisfying (1)-(3) above, and let $\phi \in Thm_\Sigma$. Let $n$ be the length of the shortest deduction of $\phi$. To show that $\phi \in C$, we proceed by induction on $n$.
Base Case: $n = 1$
If the shortest deduction of $\phi$ has length 1, then $\phi$ must be either a logical or nonlogical axiom, so either $\phi \in \Sigma$ or $\phi \in \Lambda$. Since $\Sigma, \Lambda \subseteq C$, then $\phi \in C$.
Inductive Step: $n \rightarrow n+1$
Suppose that if the shortest deduction of $\phi$ has length $n$, then $\phi \in C$. We want to show the same for $n+1$. So suppose that $\phi$ has a deduction of length $n+1$:
$D = \phi_1, \phi_2, ..., \phi_n, \phi$,
where we've written $\phi_{n+1} = \phi$.
Clearly, $\phi$ cannot be a logical or nonlogical axiom, since the shortest deduction would be of length 1 (just $D = \phi$), instead of $n+1$. Therefore, it must be justified by virtue of a rule of inference $(\Gamma, \phi)$, where $\Gamma \subseteq \{\phi_1, \phi_2, ..., \phi_n \}$.
...
From here, I'm a bit stuck. I suspect that what i'm supposed to do is use the inductive hypothesis to conclude that all the $\phi_i$ are elements of $C$, and invoke (3) to conclude that $\phi \in C$. But the way I defined $n$ was as the shortest deduction of $\phi$, not the rest of the $\phi_i$.
Another thing is that I'm assuming that the theorem is true for a particular $n$, but the $\phi_i$ will not, in general, have deductions of length $n$. I could maybe fix this by using a strong induction argument, where I take the theorem to be true for every $k \leq n+1$, but I don't think that's what the authors intended.
Ultimately, I think I'm going about the whole thing wrong, maybe I'm doing the induction in the wrong place? Or maybe my definition of $n$ is incorrect?
